# The RemoteEnvironment cannot be used when submitting a program through a client, or running in a TestEnvironment context

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-kafkaio

I was trying to execute the apache-beam word count having Kafka as input and output. But on submitting the jar to the flink cluster, this error came -

```
The RemoteEnvironment cannot be used when submitting a program through a client, or running in a TestEnvironment context.
    org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.RemoteStreamEnvironment.<init>(RemoteStreamEnvironment.java:174)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.RemoteStreamEnvironment.<init>(RemoteStreamEnvironment.java:142)
    org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkExecutionEnvironments$BeamFlinkRemoteStreamEnvironment.<init>(FlinkExecutionEnvironments.java:331)
    org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkExecutionEnvironments.createStreamExecutionEnvironment(FlinkExecutionEnvironments.java:180)
    org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkExecutionEnvironments.createStreamExecutionEnvironment(FlinkExecutionEnvironments.java:141)
    org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.translate(FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.java:98)
    org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkRunner.run(FlinkRunner.java:110)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:315)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:301)
    org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.runWordCount(WordCount.java:295)
    org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:406)
```

the command I used to submit jar -

```
./flink run -m localhost:8081 --class org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount /users/word-count-beam/target/word-count-beam-bundled-0.1.jar --runner=FlinkRunner --flinkMaster=localhost   --parallelism=2  --checkpointingInterval=10000 --checkpointTimeoutMillis=5000 --minPauseBetweenCheckpoints=500
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you use StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment, thats way you cannot submit your jar with 'flink run', you have to run it as regular java jar (java -jar ...).

If you want submit it in your cluster you should use StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment, it will return the executionEnvironment of the cluster been submitted.